# YARN: running yarn-env.sh gives error

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run YARN but running yarn-config.sh gives he following error. How can I fix it? Is it related to the kind of shell I am using?

```
sh libexec/yarn-config.sh
libexec/yarn-config.sh: 82: /opt/hadoop/2.5.1/libexec/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: why do you need to run config.sh ,why you are not running start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh ?

Comment: Try running bash -x ..../hadoop-config.sh to see what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the shell. Using bash solved the problem:

```
bash libexec/yarn-config.sh
```